# How to find all combinations of ordered symbols in Perl

Tags: perl

Say I have a set of letters.

```
my @set = qw( A C E );
```

How can I find all the ordered combinations of the letters in this set

```
A C E
A C
A E
C E
A
C
E
```

The number of symbols in the set will vary.

Comment: Your question was very hard to understand. Feel free to revert my edit if you feel I mischaracterized it in my edit.

Comment: Those are actually the *unordered* combinations ("combinations"). There are far more ordered combinations ("permutations"). e.g. When order matters, `A C E` and `A E C` aren't the same.

Comment: Yes, I should use "permutation". All possible permutation for each Name. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]. You are expected to attempt a solution to your problem before posting, and show what you've done.  SO is not a site where other people do your work for you.

Comment: ok, now I'm confused. Do you want both ACE and AEC to be output (permutations) or just ACE (combinations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) module from CPAN

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);

my @set = qw( A C E );

for my $num (1 .. +@set) {
    my $combination = combinations(\@set, $num);
    while (my $pair = $combination->next) {
        print "@$pair\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
A
C
E
A C
A E
C E
A C E
```

Answer (score 1):

*Below is code that produces combinations as the question requested. In a comment, the OP said he actually wanted permutations instead. If that's truly what he wants, they can easily be obtained by `NextPermute` from the same module.*

---

Since you have no repeating symbols, you can use something like this:

```
my @set = qw( A C E );

say "{}";
for my $s1 (0..$#set) {
   say "{", join(',', $set[ $s1 ]), "}";
   for my $s2 ($s1+1..$#set) {
      say "{", join(',', @set[ $s1, $s2 ]), "}";
      for my $s3 ($s2+1..$#set) {
         say "{", join(',', @set[ $s1, $s2, $s3 ]), "}";
      }
   }
}
```

But that presumes you know the number of symbols in the set. We can use `NestedLoops` to build these nested loops for us.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @set = qw( A C E );

my $iter = NestedLoops(
   [
      [ 0..$#set ],
      ( sub { [ $_+1..$#set ] } ) x $#set,
   ],
   { OnlyWhen => 1 },
);

say "{}";
while (my @c = $iter->()) {
   say "{", join(',', @set[@c]), "}";
}
```

Both output

```
{}
{A}
{A,C}
{A,C,E}
{A,E}
{C}
{C,E}
{E}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very helpful. I am from Biochemistry and not familiar with programming. I will try to study and program myself before asking next time. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Funny Question ! 
 But I can not use perl This is C .
I come from China, please forgive my English.
```

```
#include<stdio.h>

char chars[27];
int bitstatus[27];
int countbits(char* words);
void func(int id,int count,int* countstatus,char* chars);
int main(){ 
    printf("Input chars with no blank:");
    scanf("%s",chars);
    int count=countbits(chars);
    func(1,count,bitstatus,chars);  
return 0;
}

int countbits(char* words){
    int count=0;
    while(*words++)
        count++;
return count;
}

void func(int id,int count,int* countstatus,char* chars){
    if(id<=count){
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
        {
            countstatus[id]=i;
            func(id+1,count,countstatus,chars); //In Next   
        }
    }
    else{
        int showid;
        for(showid=1;showid<=count;showid++)
        {
        if(countstatus[showid])
        {   
           printf("%c",chars[showid-1]);
        }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If permutations are what you wanted then you can use this recursive solution.

```
$ cat perm.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @s =  @ARGV;

sub swap {
        my $i           = shift;
        my $j           = shift;
        my $tmp         = $s[$i];
        $s[$i]          = $s[$j];
        $s[$j]          = $tmp;
}

sub perm {
        my $n = shift;
        my $i = shift;

        if ( $i eq $n ) {
                print join ",", @s;
                print "\n";
        } else {
                for ( my $j=$i; $j<$n; $j++ ) {
                        swap( $i, $j );
                        perm( $n, $i+1);
                        swap( $i, $j );
                }
        }
}

perm( $#s+1, 0 );

$ ./perm.pl A B C
A,B,C
A,C,B
B,A,C
B,C,A
C,B,A
C,A,B
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'combinations' (from jaypal below), use 'subsets' to get the powerset.

```
use Algorithm::Combinatorics 'subsets';

my @set = qw/ A C E /;

my @pwrset = subsets(\@set);

print "[@$_]\n" for @pwrset;
```

Prints

```
[A C E]
[C E]
[A E]
[E]
[A C]
[C]
[A]
[]
```